# How do I exclude a port from OpenVPN on Raspbian?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

I am running an OpenVPN tunnel 24/7 on my RaspberryPI, but also want to reach it under my real public IP address with port 25565.
I forwarded the port already with my router, and without OpenVPN enabled the port is opened and working.

Tested via `ncat -l 25565`, and `https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/`

But if I enable the VPN again, it obviously doesn't work, from this I conclude that I need to exclude port `25565` from the OpenVPN tunnel.

From googling around I came to iptables, but that didn't seem to work.

- Gateway is 192.168.1.1
- Raspberry is 192.168.1.103

I tried:

- Adding iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p udp --dport 25565 --sport 1024:65535 -d 192.168.1.1 -m state --state NEW<br>
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 25565 --sport 1024:65535 -d 192.168.1.1 -m state --state NEW<br>
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i pppoe_dsl -p udp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.103:25565<br>
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i pppoe_dsl -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.103:25565
```

- Adding this at the end of the OpenVPN configuration file:

```
route 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
```

I just can't get it to work. Can someone can help me, please?

My VPN provider is PIA, and this is my configuration file (.... = certificates):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote czech.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server

auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/login.conf
compress
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
<crl-verify>
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----
 ....
-----END X509 CRL-----
</crl-verify>

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 .... 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

disable-occ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:
added this to my openvpn config file:

```
script-security 2
route-up /etc/openvpn/route-up.sh
```

route-up.sh contains:

```
ip route flush table 100
ip route flush cache

sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.103 table 100
sudo ip route add table 100 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
sudo ip route add table 100 default via 192.168.1.1
```